# Абзацное членение текста

Tags: синтаксис, литература, оформление-текста, абзац

**Можно ли разделить этот текст на 4 части?**
Слово «культура» многогранно. Что же в первую очередь несёт в себе истинная культура? Она несёт в себе понятие духовности, свет, знание и истинную красоту. И если люди поймут это, то наша страна станет процветающей.

И потому было бы очень хорошо, если бы в каждом городе и посёлке был свой центр культуры, центр творчества не только для детей, но и для людей всех возрастов. Истинная культура всегда направлена на воспитание и на образование. И во главе таких центров должны стоять люди, хорошо понимающие, что такое настоящая культура, из чего она складывается, каково её значение.

Ключевой нотой культуры могут стать такие понятия, как мир, истина, красота. Было бы хорошо, если бы культурой занимались люди честные и бескорыстные, беззаветно преданные своему делу, уважающие друг друга. Культура — огромный океан творчества, места хватит всем, для каждого найдётся дело. И если мы все вместе станем участвовать в её создании и укреплении, то вся планета наша станет прекраснее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Например, так.

1. Слово «культура» многогранно. Что же в первую очередь несёт в себе истинная культура? Она несёт в себе понятие духовности, свет, знание и истинную красоту. И если люди поймут это, то наша страна станет процветающей.
2. И потому было бы очень хорошо, если бы в каждом городе и посёлке был свой центр культуры, центр творчества не только для детей, но и для людей всех возрастов. Истинная культура всегда направлена на воспитание и на образование. И во главе таких центров должны стоять люди, хорошо понимающие, что такое настоящая культура, из чего она складывается, каково её значение.
3. Ключевой нотой культуры могут стать такие понятия, как мир, истина, красота. Было бы хорошо, если бы культурой занимались люди честные и бескорыстные, беззаветно преданные своему делу, уважающие друг друга.
4. Культура — огромный океан творчества, места хватит всем, для каждого найдётся дело. И если мы все вместе станем участвовать в её создании и укреплении, то вся планета наша станет прекраснее.

То есть делим 3-й абзац на две части:

- в первой говорится о ключевой ноте культуры (мир, истина, красота) и соответствующих людях, которые занимаются "такой" культурой (честные, бескорыстные, преданные делу, уважающие друг друга);
- во второй говорится о культуре как об океане творчества, где всем хватит места, и о том, что люди, сообща создавая культуру, способны сделать мир лучше.